# Swift: Empty space adding while converting html string to attribute string

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Receiving `HTML` type `String` from `API` .

Converting `HTML` to `NSAttributeString` --> Facing empty Space issue by `Unicode` - `\u200b`

How to remove this white space from `HTML` to `NSAttributeString` ?

**API Response:**

```
{
    "message" : "[<b>1-</b> Fill\U200b t\U200bhe \U200b\U200b\U200bBreak Do\U200bwn Table]"
}
```

**Struct - Decoder:**

```
{
    "message" : "[<b>1-</b> Fill the Break Down Table]"
}
```

**UILabel Text:**

```
labet.text = Message.message // [<b>1-</b> Fill the Break Down Table] - SHOWING IN UI
```

**UILabel Attribute text:**

```
labet.attributedText = Message.message.htmlAttributedString()
```

**Attribute Output:**

[image: attribute_output]       `- SHOWING IN UI`

**Extension Code:**

```
func htmlAttributedString() -> NSMutableAttributedString {

    guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        else { return NSMutableAttributedString() }

    guard let formattedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data,
                                                    options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                              .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                                    documentAttributes: nil )

     else { return NSMutableAttributedString() }

    return formattedString
}
```

Can any one guide me on this ? How to avoid this space ?

Comment: Just replace the unicode space with a blank string using [replacingOccurrences](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416484-replacingoccurrences).

Comment: The `\U200b` is unicode for a zero-width space. I'm not sure why it's being displayed as an actual space in your UI, nor am I sure why those characters appear at all. As others have suggested, just strip them out.

Comment: Yes., that's my doubt., in attributedText "\u{200B}" - Space is appearing , in label.text "\u{200B}" - Space is not appearing

Comment: @DuncanC do u know concept behind this ?

Comment: The `.characterEncoding` needs to have an `NSNumber` value.

Comment: You could also try including an inout dict reference of `[.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]` for the `documentAttrributes` param.

Comment: I have used like that only. Correct me, if I m wrong @PranavKasetti

Comment: This is the correct way to input a char encoding: `.characterEncoding: NSNumber(value: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)`

Comment: No. You have not done that, same for the doc attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
labet.attributedText = Message.message.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{200B}", with: "").htmlAttributedString()
```

Comment: yes. It is working., Earlier., I thought swift unicode syntax is different from api response's unicode.

Comment: Why not just filter?

Comment: @LeoDabus Just wrote the first one that came into my mind. It could be filter as well, I think it even suits better for this case.

Comment: @LeoDabus That's my doubt., in attributedText "\u{200B}" - Space is appearing , in label.text "\u{200B}" - Space is not appearing ??

Comment: @McDonal_11 It's not about label. This is due to `DocumentType.html` option of attributed string which uses WebKit behind the scenes to render html. I think that's why this unicode is recognized. If you just try it with a regular attributed string there will be no spaces displayed.